# Series of books about a young man who is promoted to captain of a starship on his first trip

Tags: story-identification, books

Things I remember:

- There are only a few inhabited worlds
- Travel between planets takes months
- There is an alien species, that travel in space without ships, which resembles giant blobs.
- The protagonist starts as about 17 years old, and grows to old age in about six books.

Comment: Not the answer to the question but the [Larry Niven short-story "One Face"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconstant_Moon#One_Face) sees a passenger promoted to command as a desperate measure. Alas the astrophysics is a bit dated, but the story is still good fun.

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds to me like you're talking about the books in the Seafort Saga.  The first novel is titled 'Midshipman's Hope', and according to Wikipedia, the author's name is David Feintuch.  [The summary of 'Midshipman's Hope' on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midshipman%27s_Hope) does mesh in with the points you've listed, so I'm fairly confidant this is what you're thinking about.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Andpato Welcome to Stack Exchange! The best way to indicate that this answer is correct and to thank the answerer is to [mark the answer as accepted by ticking the check mark next to it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: This sounds suspiciously similar to Horatio Hornblower in space... (same way Weber's Honor Harrington is).

Comment: The series is modeled very closely to Hornblower. Much closer than Honor Harrington.